# React component + Axios import

Tags: reactjs, import, axios, components

I have a React app and want to import Axios library to React component. But if I try to use Axios inside the component it is undefined. I mean this style:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

Instead I have to write:

```
window.axios = require('axios').default;
```

and then call window.axios. This is the only way it works. Is it possible to cast away window from axios calls?

React component is class style:

```
class Login extends React.Component
{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: []
        }
    }

    ...

    sendData(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.set('email', this.state.email);
        formData.set('password', this.state.password);

        // This is nasty
        window.axios({
            ...
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                ...
            })
            .catch(response => {
                ...
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

So the question is how to cast away window call from calling axios. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the package.json to your question, so that we can know axios is added correctly and the version of axios. Thanks.

Comment: Axios is added correctly. It works fine. The problem was the file where I was importing axios. It was the parent file and it should be component file.

Answer (score 0):

You should import axios like this:

```
import * as axios from 'axios'
```

Side note: try to keep your component cleaned from network request, if you really do need those, put them in a separe file (or redux + thunk)

Comment: The problem was I imported axios in the parent file. So the scope was out of the component. If I move import to component file it works and window is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I imported axios in the parent file. So the scope was out of the component.  It should be imported in the file where compoentns code is stored. If I move import to component file it works and window is not needed.